# the entry point function of Isolate can not marked as async

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

The example of isolate in [flutter](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/)! does not work. the new isolate does not run. but if I remove the ***async*** of entry point function. it works fine. So, How can I make await operation in a new isolate in flutter.

Comment: That's a big page you linked to. Can you please provide more concrete information what code causes you troubles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a Dart 2 bug.

If `async` doesn't work, you can always use `.then()` instead of `async` and `await` to chain async calls.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem whilst moving code from the main isolate to another one. in my case i move async method channel calls which stopped working afterwards in the new isolate. in the main isolate the calls blocked the ui.

found the following

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16846